# Prerequisites "Homology Theory of Algebraic Varieties" by Wallace

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-topology

I bought this book because the title was very interesting, the description as well and the price very cheap. You can read it [here](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/wallace.pdf) in PDF.

Unfortunately, I realized after reading the first lines I was not very comfortable with the notions. For example : what is an absolutely irreducible variety ? What is a "specialization" of a point ? So before continuing to read this I wanted to  be sure to have the necessary basis.

> What papers/books I have to read for be able to understood this book ?

I have followed one course in algebraic geometry and one basic course in algebraic topology.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I *believe* that "absolutely irreducible" and "geometrically irreducible" are the same. That, along with a definition of specialization, should be in Hartshorne. Probably both are in II.3.

Comment: The book is written in such old-fashioned language that it is practically impossible to read for a modern mathematician. Instead  I recommend the following very clear  notes by [Nicolaescu](http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/sing.pdf) , freely available online.

Comment: I agree, more or less, with Georges: this book does seem quite outdated in its language (albeit not to the same extent as, say, Hodge & Pedoe). It is also curiously low on content: at a glance, it seems mostly to consist of lengthy technical arguments proving Lefschetz's theorems. That's fine, of course, but a textbook should cover more ground. Another alternative source would be "Hodge Theory and Complex Algebraic Geometry, Volume 1" by Claire Voisin.

Comment: Oh, and I agree with @Hoot too! "Absolutely irreducible" is the same as "geometrically irreducible". On the other hand I don't think (correct me if I'm wrong) Hartshorne defines "specialization"; that seems to be one of those notions that was very prominent in algebraic geometry before the Age of Schemes, but was then relegated to a minor role.

Comment: @Relapsarian He defines it in an exercise (of course!), II.3.17. He actually uses the word quite a bit when talking about valuative criteria (not a high point in the book) but never again.

Comment: The introduction seems to indicate that what is proved is beyond what most introductory texts call Lefschetz theorems but I might be wrong about this — my complex geometry is just that weak. And it seems to be for arbitrary fields, and I don't know where to look for *that* besides SGA2. Anyway, I'm completely out of my depth now. Thank you to Georges for the reference!

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the answers, in particular Georges for this reference which looks more accessible for me.

Comment: @Hoot: thanks for the reference for specialisations in Hartshorne! I didn't mean to suggest the Wallace book only contains the Lefschetz theorems, just that those proofs occupy a huge chunk of it. They need to be written somewhere, of course, but it doesn't make for a good introductory text.

Comment: Also, I just note that it definitely only treats complex varieites. Skim through and you will find all kinds of arguments using differential topology. More basically, what are the homology groups in question if the base field isn't $\mathbf C$?

Comment: @Relapsarian I'm not sure. I just skimmed the intro and the first few pages; he said the ground field could be arbitrary, so I figured there was some combination of the foundations from Weil and Chevalley that made this all possible. Maybe five pages later he says, "but really, everything over $\mathbb{C}$. I really don't know enough about what was available. I think the suggestion to read one of the modern complex geometry texts that talks about this stuff is the right one, anyway.